# write java.util.logging to a file

Tags: java, logging, file-io, nullpointerexception, java.util.logging

While I'm aware of [Log4J](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j), and I'm sure there are others, I'm using [`java.util.logging`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) to write to a file.

The error originates in `nextTitleActionPerformed` which is near the bottom of the soure code.

I've looked at a few questions on SO, but must be misunderstanding the mechanism for logging to a file.

However, logging to a file results in a `NullPointerException` as below:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
Jul 27, 2014 12:21:50 AM net.bounceme.dur.client.gui.LoggingGUI <init>
INFO: starting log..
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.bounceme.dur.client.gui.LoggingGUI.nextTitleActionPerformed(LoggingGUI.java:103)
    at net.bounceme.dur.client.gui.LoggingGUI.access$000(LoggingGUI.java:10)
    at net.bounceme.dur.client.gui.LoggingGUI$2.actionPerformed(LoggingGUI.java:56)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3311)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/Log$
```

Apparently, I'm not attaching the handler correctly?

code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.client.gui;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public final class LoggingGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoggingGUI.class.getName());
    private Title title = null;
    private FileHandler fh = null;

    public LoggingGUI() throws IOException {
        initComponents();
        fh = new FileHandler("gui.log");
        log.addHandler(fh);
        log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        log.info("starting log..");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new LoggingGUI().setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(LoggingGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        stateGroup = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        titlePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        nextTitle = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        nextTitle.setText("next");
        nextTitle.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                nextTitleActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout titlePanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(titlePanel);
        titlePanel.setLayout(titlePanelLayout);
        titlePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            titlePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(titlePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(94, 94, 94)
                .addComponent(nextTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 557, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(144, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        titlePanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            titlePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(titlePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(73, 73, 73)
                .addComponent(nextTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 286, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(101, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab1", titlePanel);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 803, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jTabbedPane1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void nextTitleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        title = null;
        Date date = new Date();
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        log.info(title.toString());
        title.setTitle("modified from GUI");
    }                                         


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    private javax.swing.JButton nextTitle;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup stateGroup;
    private javax.swing.JPanel titlePanel;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}




handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level=ALL

myapp.ui.level=ALL
myapp.business.level=CONFIG
myapp.data.level=SEVERE
net.bounceme.dur.level=ALL

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=SEVERE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=%h/java%u.log

java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=50000

java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=1

java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

clicking the button causes the error.

see also:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while youre right that most devs shun java.util.logging in favor of something better, your issue isnt related to logging at all:

```
title = null; <---- null
Date date = new Date();
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
log.info(title.toString());  <---- STILL null
title.setTitle("modified from GUI");
```

Comment: is this a limitation of the logger, that it will crash, or not log, at least, when hit with an exception?  Seems rather pointless if the **logger** fails to write an exception to the log file.  Why didn't it write that error to the file?  It had no problem dumping it to the console.

Comment: @Thufir - no, the evaluation of "title.toString()" comes 1st (and explodes) and only then would the resulting string have been handed to the logger. if you were to use slf4j, for example, you could do something like log.info("title is {}",title) and the logging framework will do the String composition for you, avoiding NPEs (and faster if info is off)